# performing a select on a c# datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have a datatable with a bunch of rows in it, the first column is an `Int32` and I want to perform a simple select like:

```
select * from MyDataTable where column1 = 234
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this to get result as row array :

```
DataRow[] rows = myDataTable.Select("column1 = 234");
```

Or this to get dataview :

```
DataView myDataView = myDataTable.DefaultView;
myDataView.RowFilter = "column1 = 234";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
             where row[0].Equals(42)
             select row;
```

Or

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row[0].Equals(42));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're talking of a System.Data.DataTable, you can use datatable.Rows.Find  for searching a row by primaryKey,  or datatable.Select for obtaining a array of rows that satisfy your condition.

// By DataTable's primary key

```
datatable.Rows.Find(234);
```

// By compound primary key

```
datatable.Rows.Find(234, 1, 4);
```

// by Select

```
datatable.Select("column1=234");
```

// by Compound Select

```
datatable.Select("column1=234 AND column2=1");
```